Google Cloud - Migrate or integrate existing Google Adwords with a new Google Organizational Tenant
I hope this is in the correct section of the forum, if not an administrator can move the post to the correct place.
Our organization has an existing Google Adwords (G4) that currently a few members of our organization is using and administrating.
This instance of Google Adwords (G4) is currently not connected to our organization.
We want to setup SSO with Azure AD but for this to work the Adwords need to be connected to the organization.
How can we do this?
Do we need to create a new google cloud organization and then integrate/connect it to the current Adwords - Or do we need to migrate everything to the new google cloud organization?
We have tried finding the answers for this in the Google Adwords account and in the Google Cloud organizational account, but have not found any information. Is there anyone that has done this or have any recommendations regarding this?
